# Uncaught Error: Unable to recognize DataType for: Edm.Self.Address with breezejs

Tags: javascript, entity-framework, breeze

I get the error when trying to use breezejs, the type is a complex type from entity framework (code first).

Uncaught Error: Unable to recognize DataType for: Edm.Self.Address

Are there any workarounds for using complex types with breezejs?.
from my entity framework model:

```
public class Address
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string Contry { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breeze does not yet support Entity Framework Complex types.  It is on our roadmap but we are not there yet. Please vote for this feature on the Breeze website (www.breezejs.com).

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to [JayData](http://jaydata.codeplex.com), it supports complex types for query or for crud. Once you have a working OData endpoint at address http://{yourdomain}/{yourapi}, you can just use it without any further ado:

```
<script src="http://include.jaydata.org/datajs-1.0.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://include.jaydata.org/jaydata.js"></script>
<script src="http://include.jaydata.org/jaydataproviders/oDataProvider.js"></script>
<script>
  $data.service("http://{yourdomain}/{yourapi}", function(contextFactory) {
  var context = contextFactory();
  context
   .myEntitySet
   .filter(function(item) { return item.ComplexProp.Field == 42 || item.Title =="Tea"})
   .forEach(function(item) { 
       console.log(item.Title);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Note that with JayData you can use TypeScript for any OData endpoint. Using TypeScript gives you

- strongly typed client experience
- fantastic hints on features
- lambda predicates:  filter(item => item.ComplexType.Field == 42)

read [more here](http://jaystack.com/blog/typescript-meets-odata-with-the-help-of-jaydata-and-jaysvcutil)

Comment: Thanks, great to know about other options. I might use some hours looking into it.

Answer (score 1):

As of v 0.80.1, breeze now supports complex types. Hope this helps.